# ValueError: embedded null byte

Tags: python

Mac OS, Python3.7, Mysqlbd

Помогите, пожалуйста. Необходимо достать блоб и записать его в файл. В таблице, собственно, присутствуют два поля - сам блоб и имя файла в кириллице, с пробелами.

При попытке взять название этого файла и записать в него блоб, вылезает ошибка из сабжа. Если конвертировать название файла, взятое из таблицы, в байты, то видно, что в конце названия, после расширения, идут нулевые байты. Если подставить вместо него какой-нибудь `/tmp/test.doc`, то всё ок. Да даже `/tmp/тест`  хренова туча пробелов. doc - всё ок.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать. Спасибo!

```
import MySQLdb
import string
import os


db=MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user='root',passwd='password' ,
                   db='documents',charset='utf8')


def write_file(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)

def read_blob():
    sql="""select DocFile,FileName from DocFiles where 
    DocID='793E2699375542F4C325760A004A65FA'"""

    try:
            cursor=db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result=cursor.fetchone()
            file_result=result[0]
            filename=result[1]

            write_file(file_result,filename)

    finally:
            cursor.close()
            db.close()

read_blob()
```

Comment: при извлечении из таблицы имя файла имеет недопустимые символы, кодировку или т.п. проверьте что у вас там подставляется

Comment: Нужно видеть структуру вашей таблицы `DocFiles`.

Comment: А как её Вам предоставить? там есть три столбца, DocID, DocFile(сам блоб) и, соответственно, FileName. А как проверить в какой кодировке он забирает из таблицы или сразу конвертировать в правильную(какую?)? Пробовал переводить в UTF-8, результат тот же. К примеру, есть FileName УспешныйПроект.doc. При os.fsencode видно, что после .doc куча x00 данных, они-то, наверное и мешают?

Comment: Какие типы этих столбцов? Лучше всего, какой командой `CREATE TABLE` была таблица `DocFiles` создана?

Comment: Не известно, это старый коробочный битрикс. Может быть есть какой-то костыль, который возьмёт строку и, не знаю как объяснить, оставит её просто строкой в UTF8, без каких-то непонятных бит в конце имени?